# How to show that there is a deduction of $\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Problem is showing or disproving in Sentential logic that:

If $\Sigma$$\vdash$$\varphi$ iff $\Sigma$$\vdash$$\psi$, then
 $\Sigma$$\vdash$$\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$

But I wonder how to show that there exists(or there's no) such a deduction.

To show opposite direction, I write as follows:

Suppose that $\Sigma\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$
 , i.e. there exists a deduction $<a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}>$
 such that $a_{n}=\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$
 . Then assume $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$
 , i.e. there exists a deduction $<b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{m}>$
  such that $b_{m}=\varphi$
 . Then a sequence $ <a_{1},\cdots,a_{n},b_{1},\cdots,b_{m},\psi>$
  is a deduction from $\Sigma$
  to $\psi$
 . Thus, $\Sigma\vdash\psi$
 . Then assume that $\Sigma\vdash\psi$
 , i.e. there exists a sequence $<c_{1},c_{2},\cdots,c_{l}>$
  such that $c_{l}=\psi$
 . Then a sequence $<a_{1},\cdots,a_{n},c_{1},\cdots,c_{l},\varphi>$
  is a deduction from $\Sigma$
  to $\varphi$
 . Thus, $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$
 . Thus, If $\Sigma\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$
 , then $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$
  iff $\Sigma\vdash\psi$
 .

It seem to me that it is similar to this one. But I don't know how to do it.

This is my new answer:

Comsider $\Sigma=\{p,q\}$
 . Then $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$
  and $\Sigma\vdash\psi$
 . Thus, $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$
  iff $\Sigma\vdash\psi$
 . But for a truth assignment $\nu$
  of $\Sigma$
  such that $\bar{\nu}(\varphi)=T$
  and $\bar{\nu}(\psi)=F$
 , $\bar{\nu}(\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi)=F$
 . Thus, $\Sigma\nvDash\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$
 . It means that, by completeness of Sentential Logic, $\Sigma\nvdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$
 .

Deduction from $\Sigma$  is a finite sequence of sentences which consists of  members of $\Sigma$ , tautology, or sentences obtained by Modus Ponens

And biconditional is not a part of this language.

Comment: I don't think it is true.  Let $\Sigma$ be an incomplete theory and $\varphi, \psi$ two sentences that may or may not be true.  For example, the theory of groups, $\varphi$ that the group is abelian, $\psi$ that the group has at least four elements.  $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ iff $\Sigma \vdash \psi$, but $\Sigma \not \vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$

Comment: For that matter, suppose $\Sigma=\emptyset$, $\phi=p$, and $\psi=q$.

Comment: @Darae-Uri Do you know the completeness theorem yet? Is $\leftrightarrow$ part of the language or is it an abbreviation? If it is part of the language, how exactly do you define *deduction*?

Comment: @RossMillikan The problem is in Sentential Logic (A.K.A. Propositional Calculus).

Comment: @GitGud I know it. Using completeness, I answered it. I was asking new question for my "new answer" to this problem, right befor your comment. I will edit this question to add my new answer but I'm not sure it is correcy

Comment: @Darae-Uri What are $\varphi$ and $\psi$ in your proposed counter-example?

Comment: @GitGud Sorry for typo. I meant that p=$\psi$ and q=ψ

Comment: If you add that $\Sigma\vdash\neg\varphi$ or $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$, and $\Sigma\vdash\neg\psi$ or $\Sigma\vdash\psi$ I think you could proove it.

Comment: @GitGud Thank you for your comments!

Comment: @GitGud...  Are you claiming that it's not the case that $$\emptyset\vdash p\text{ iff } \emptyset\vdash q$$?

Comment: For example, because you think that $\emptyset\vdash p$ while $\emptyset \not\vdash q$?  Or is it the other way around?

Comment: @mmw I was claiming that. Why I did so, I don't understand. You're of course correct. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false.  For a counterexample, pick $\Sigma=\emptyset$, $\phi=p$, and $\psi=q$.

The soundness theorem gives that $\emptyset\not\vdash p$ and $\emptyset\not\vdash q$, hence that $\emptyset\vdash p$ iff $\emptyset\vdash q$.  But also by soundness, $\emptyset \not\vdash p\leftrightarrow q$.